# How to check if a win32 exe file is already running? (use win32 API code)

Tags: c++, c, windows, api, winapi

I want to check if a win32 EXE file is already running (only knowing the file path and name).

Please tell me how to realize it with win32 API code.

Thanks a lot!

I mean to **have each EXE path** only running one instance.

Comment: Does it have a window associated with it?

Comment: the win32 exe file being checked can be any file, despite whether it has a window or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given only a path to the EXE, you will need to enumerate the running processes until you find one with a matching path. Look at [`EnumProcesses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms682629(v=VS.85).aspx) or [`Process32First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684834(v=VS.85).aspx)/[`Process32Next()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684836(v=VS.85).aspx) for that. See [Process Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-enumeration) on MSDN for more details and code examples.

Answer (score 0):

By reading Remy Lebeau's answer I succeed to check if the current application is already running in other processes with the following code:

```
DWORD processes[4096];
DWORD bytesGot;
EnumProcesses(processes, sizeof processes, &bytesGot);
DWORD processesCount = bytesGot / sizeof(DWORD);

WCHAR currName[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameEx(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, currName, MAX_PATH);
DWORD currProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();

for(int x=0;x<=processesCount-1;x++)
{
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processes[x]);
    WCHAR name[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameEx(process,NULL, name, MAX_PATH);
    CloseHandle(process);
    if (processes[x]!=currProcessId&& wcscmp(name, currName)==0) return 0;
}
```

Thanks to Remy Lebeau a lot :) Great useful hints.

Comment: This sort of code I wrote is to prevent one EXE file from running two or more processes.

Comment: That's the wrong solution to that problem. Use a named murex to do that. Also this code has no error checking.

Comment: @David Heffernan how is that wrong?

Comment: Well, it's subject to a race. Perfectly possible for two instances of the process to start. The way to solve your problem is to use a named mutex. There are many examples here and in other places. If only you'd asked about your problem rather than your solution.

Comment: Also trivially defeated by changing the executable file name.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make it clear. I mean to have _**each EXE file path**_ running only one instance, not that to have _**this product**_ running only one instance. Therefore, this code solves it well for me.

Comment: So the user just creates a copy of the exe file and hey presto, that one program be run run twice.

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes

Answer (score -3):

create a blank file on startup and check the file exist.

Comment: This solution is bad because you have no guarantee that someone will not manually delete the file. If so, you'll consider that the _.exe_ is not running despite it still is. Wasn't me that has downvoted though.